# Azure DevOps: Set Git branch permission for all repos in all projects

Tags: git, permissions, azure-devops, azure-repos

Is there a way to set the "Force Push" permission for a group in Azure DevOps for all current and future branches in all current and future repos and projects?

We currently have about 50 projects with one repo and several branches each and it would be a lot of manual work and error prone to set the permission in every single branch for every repository.

Answer (score 8):

If you navigate to the project settings, then select `Repositories` in the left pane, you can select the `Git repositories` root in the tree view. Any permission explicitly defined here is inherited by all existing and new repositories and branches:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I misworded my question. Our repos are in different projects, so I still would have to do this about 50 times. Although this is the best solution yet.

Comment: I don't think there's a friendly way to do this through the UI. If you really don't want to bounce in and out of the UI for your separate projects you could probably script it out using the [Security API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: Although the script will help with existing projects, it won't cover the new ones, unfortunately. So, once you create a new project, you'll have not to forget to configure this thing.

Comment: I think things have changed in the last 4 years. I wasn't able to do it at a root for all repos at once but at least I didn't have to click on every single branch with this hint.

Answer (score 2):

[Jesse Houwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079) wrote recently [an article](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions) about it, in short, you can use `tfssecurity` command to apply git permissions for all repositories in all projects:

```
tfssecurity /a+ "Git Repositories" repoV2/ "ForcePush" adm: ALLOW /collection:https://dev.azure.com/{organization}
```

Explanation:

`/a+` - Add (a+) or Remove (a-) this permissions.

`Git Repositories` - The Security Namespace

`repoV2` - The token for organization level

`ForcePush` - The Permissions we want to set

`adm:` - The Group (in this case "Project Collection Administrators")

`ALLOW` - Allow or Deny the permission

I recommend to take a look in the article to see how he found it.

More info about `tfssecurity` tool you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the permissions in Repositories for multiple projects in batches through this [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/set%20access%20control%20lists?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=5.0
```

[image]

The "Force Push" permission previously in the UI for **Not set** was changed to **Allow**.