# Set branch permissions for a group via Azure Repos API

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I need to restrict permissions for certain branches across 50 repos for specific user groups in azure repos. This is to say, a particular group of users cannot force push to the master branch but can other branches.

This is easy enough to do in the interface, but requires going to 50+ repos and manually performing this task. I've been reading through the Azure repos API documentation and I'm struggling to see how I go about setting this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652476/azure-devops-set-git-branch-permission-for-all-repos-in-all-projects

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answer the question. That targets all branches, I know how to do that... i want to target a specific branch in a repo for a specific group and permission. I can do this via the UI, so hoping an API or failing that a tool could do it.

Comment: @nullabletype, do you still have other questions? Did my answer help for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the blog post https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/:

`tfssecurity /a+ "Git Repositories" repoV2/<Team Project GUID>/<repository guid>/refs^heads^<branch name>/ "ForcePush" <memberIdentity> DENY /collection:https://dev.azure.com/{organization}`

The repository guids can be found out via REST API, where GitRepository.id contains the guid:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd?view=azure-devops for more information about how to specifiy member identity.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've been trying out the az method instead as its the newest supported method, and it all seems to work apart from the branch specification. I sent it out as refs^heads^master but in the response it returns as refsheadsmaster and the permissions are not visible in the UI. Any idea where I may be going wrong? The token for the branch seems to match what the UI uses in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below rest api to set branch permission fors for group.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectid}/_api/_security/ManagePermissions?__v=5
```

Here is a sample of request body.

```
{"updatePackage":
"{\"IsRemovingIdentity\":false,
\"TeamFoundationId\":\"{teamfoundationId}}\",
\"DescriptorIdentityType\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity\",
\"DescriptorIdentifier\":\"{DescriptorIdentifier}}\",
\"PermissionSetId\":\"2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87\",
\"PermissionSetToken\":\"repoV2/{projectId}}/{repoId}}/refs^heads^{branchname}}/\",
\"RefreshIdentities\":false,
\"Updates\":
[{\"PermissionId\":1,\"PermissionBit\":32768,\"NamespaceId\":\"2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87\",
\"Token\":\"repoV2/{projectId}/{repoId}/refs/heads/{branchId}/\"}],
\"TokenDisplayName\":null}"}
```

**Note**

`\"PermissionId\":1`, means set the permission to Allow, 
`\"PermissionId\":2`, means set the permission to Deny, 
`\"PermissionId\":1`, means set the permission to Not Set.

`\"PermissionBit\":32768` is the Bypass policies when completing pull requests permission.
`\"PermissionBit\":128` is the Bypass policies when pushing permission.

`\"PermissionBit\":4` is the Contribute policies when pushing permission.

`\"PermissionBit\":2048` is the Edit polices permission.

`\"PermissionBit\":8` is the Fource push permission.

`\"PermissionBit\":8192` is the Manage permissions.

`\"PermissionBit\":4096` is the remove other's lock permission.

**Addition**

There are too many parameters in the request body, you can get there parameters by offical documentations. Or I recommand you to get these parameters by using Network Tool to manual cathch them.